# android countdowntimer wait

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I don't understand how to `pause` the `counterdowntimer`. I have a public countdowntimer:

```
    public CountDownTimer myTimer = new CountDownTimer(300000, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        ...
        setCurrentTime(currentTime);
    }
    public void onFinish() {
        setCurrentTime("0");
    }
};
```

I can `.start()` and `.cancel()` by `buttonclick`, but I can't `.wait()`. **Dev Docs** says

> This method can only be invoked by a thread which owns this object's monitor; see notify() on how a thread can become the owner of a monitor.

what does it mean?

I tried to save `millisUntilFinished` in a variable, but how can I restart the `timer` from that value?

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a global variable eg, `private Boolean pauseTimer=false;` and then check `onTick` if the variable is true - and if it is then invoke `SystemClock.sleep()`

Comment: does systemclock.sleep() delays dev clock?

Comment: It pauses the Thread, so the Thread doesn't do anything for the given time.

Comment: it is only a delay, it ask me a delay time. how can I keep paused while pause is on?

Answer (score -1):

You can't wait() on an object unless the current thread owns that object's monitor. To do that, you must synchronize on it.